# Plotly Scattergl is unresponsive

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have used plotly's scatter and scattergl extensively for the last 2-3 years. However, for some strange reason scattergl has stopped working for the last couple of days. I can generate the html plot, but when I open it, my browser either shows the plot, but does not allow me to zoom into the plot, or prompts me that webgl is not supported by my browser (I have hardware acceleration activated.) I tried on two different computers to no avail. I tried reverting to plotly 5.3.1, but that did not work either. Not sure if there is some bug in one of the dependencies, or what is happening. I am curious if anyone is having a similar problem or has a solution. Thank you for the help.

P.S. Plotly scatter functions perfectly, but when I switch to scattergl, the html plot is unresponsive

Comment: Is the version that stops working 5.3.1? Is it the same with the latest version 5.10.0? I think you will get more comments and answers if you provide reproducible data and code.

Comment: It stopped for both versions. I will post some example code in a bit